# Swift: UIRefreshControl does not pull through when dragging down

Tags: swift, uitableview, fault, uirefreshcontrol

I have a working UITableView in which I added a UIRefreshControl like this:

```
var refresher: UIRefreshControl!
...
// this is ViewDidLoad()
    // pull to refresh
    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.tintColor = globalClass.blue
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "loadFriends", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    friendTableView.addSubview(refresher)
```

This works well on other UITableViews, but not on this one for some reason. The spinner never really spins and just snaps to the top when the dragging stops. What could cause this?

EDIT: loadFriends function

```
//load friends
func loadFriends() {
    globalClass.requestsIn = []
    globalClass.requestsOut = []
    globalClass.finalSections = []
    globalClass.myFriends = []
    finalSections = []
    sectionsG1 = []

    let queryIn1 = PFQuery(className:"Friendship")
    queryIn1.whereKey("toUser", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    let queryOut = PFQuery(className:"Friendship")
    queryOut.whereKey("fromUser", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

    let query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([queryIn1, queryOut])
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            if objects!.count == 0 {
                self.friendtTableView.reloadData()
                self.text()
            } else {
                for object in objects! {
                    let toUser:String = object["toUser"] as! String
                    let status:String = object["status"] as! String
                    if toUser == PFUser.currentUser()?.username {
                        if status == "pending" {
                            globalClass.requestsIn.append(object["fromUser"] as! String)
                            self.update()
                        } else if status == "approved" {
                            globalClass.myFriends.append(object["fromUser"] as! String)
                            globalClass.myFriends = globalClass.myFriends.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
                            self.update()
                        }
                    } else {  if status == "pending" || status == "rejected" {
                        globalClass.requestsOut.append(object["toUser"] as! String)
                        self.update()
                    } else if status == "approved" {
                        globalClass.myFriends.append(object["toUser"] as! String)
                        globalClass.myFriends = globalClass.myFriends.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
                        self.update()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if self.tableSegment == 1 {
                if globalClass.requestsIn.count == 0 {
                    self.friendTableView.reloadData()
                    self.text()
                } else {
                }
            } else if self.tableSegment == 2 {
                if globalClass.requestsOut.count == 0 {
                    self.friendTableView.reloadData()
                    self.text()
                } else {
                }
            } else if self.tableSegment == 0 {
                if globalClass.myFriends.count == 0 {
                    self.friendTableView.reloadData()
                    self.text()
                } else {
                }
            }
            self.refresher.endRefreshing()
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you use the start refreshing method for it to start spinning ? and also post your whole code

Comment: I tried that but that didn't work. My whole code would be unnecessary; what's missing?

Comment: The action is never triggered.

Comment: you are not giving us enough code for us to know what is not working, can you post the loadFriends function

Comment: Edited. But as I said, this function is never triggered.